# adding text of a div to a list by clicking and removing it by click on same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make some div's with `jquery` that by clicking on them I can add their text into a list and by clicking again on that div I can remove just that div's text from the list, not all of them.
but when I order to remove by clicking again on that div all text remove's from list

```js
$(".first-div").on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("div2 active");

  let matn = $("<h3>" + $(this).html() + "</h3>");

  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(".textbox").append(matn);
  } else {
    $(".textbox").children("h5").html($(this).html()).remove();
  }

})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 3em;
}

.first-div {
  padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
  background-color: silver;
  margin: 2em 0;
  border: 2px solid silver;
}

.div2 {
  border-color: red;
}

.text {
  margin-top: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.textbox {
  padding: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="first-div">
      <h5>text1</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="first-div">
      <h5>text2</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="first-div">
      <h5>text3</h5>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="text">
    <div class="textbox"></div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: ok but have you tried anything? any code you can provide us with so we can help you?

Comment: @Bargros there are code snippet though?

Comment: Whoops I did not see it, sorry. Thank you @Mukyuu

Comment: @Bargros I wrote them under description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler pattern to follow is to build the entire list everytime a change is made, instead of having to maintain the array when an item is selected/deselected.

Also note that your current example is nesting `<h5>` elements within `<h3>`, which is invalid.

```js
$(".first-div").on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("div2 active");
  let matn = $('.first-div.active').map(function() {
    return $(this).html();
  }).get();
  $(".textbox").html(matn);
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 3em;
}

.first-div {
  padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
  background-color: silver;
  margin: 2em 0;
  border: 2px solid silver;
}

.div2 {
  border-color: red;
}

.text {
  margin-top: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.textbox {
  padding: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="first-div">
    <h5>text1</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="first-div">
    <h5>text2</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="first-div">
    <h5>text3</h5>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="text">
  <div class="textbox"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just find the element that contains the text and remove it from the list like this:

```
$(".first-div").on('click', function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("div2 active");

   let matn = $("<h3>" + $(this).html() + "</h3>");

   if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
     $(".textbox").append(matn);
   } else {
     $(".textbox").find("h5:contains(" + $(this).text().trim() + ")").remove();
   }

 })
```

In your code just change this:

```
$(".textbox").children("h5").html($(this).html()).remove();
```

to this:

```
$(".textbox").find("h5:contains(" + $(this).text().trim() + ")").remove();
```

**[Here is the JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zLy6co3a/)**